# Cambiar varios diccionarios en específico

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

El objetivo de esta función es el siguiente: primero recibe una cadena de texto idéntica a la anidación de diccionarios que se desea cambiar (para ir directamente a la raíz y los sub-diccionarios que se desean cambiar), segundo recibirá una segunda cadena que deberá reemplazar varios diccionarios de una raiz sin eliminar sus subdiccionarios, deberia funcionar de esta manera, se hace un split de ambas entradas, si (`Yo`) esta en el dic, y (`Yo`) es diferente de (`Ella`) entonces el diccionario (`Yo`) se copia en (`Ella`) y luego (`Yo`) se elimina quedando (`Ella`) con su contenido, se guarda la posicion en el subdiccionario al final con (`dic=dic[palabrac]`) para seguir reemplazando lo siguiente, se regresa en el For ahora se verifica si (`soy`) esta en el dic y si (`soy`) es diferente de (`es`) ocurrira el reemplazo pero ocurre un error extraño.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PYTHON\Python Full\CODIGOS GUARDADOS\CODIGOS INFO\Alice 1.10.11.py", line 258, in <module>
    corregir(entrada1,corregido1)
  File "F:\PYTHON\Python Full\CODIGOS GUARDADOS\CODIGOS INFO\Alice 1.10.11.py", line 226, in corregir
    print("Final dic palabrac: ",dic[palabrac])
KeyError: 'es'
```

La funcion que obtiene el error es ésta.

```py
def corregir(oracione, oracionc):
    """
    Esta funcion reemplaza palabras, busca todas las palabras de un diccionario
    en especifico usando una cadena de texto que especifica la ruta compara si
    es igual y remplaza el viejo nombre por la diferencia
    """

    dic = conceptos_de_mi

    for palabrae in oracione.split():
        for palabrac in oracionc.split():
            if palabrae in dic and palabrae != palabrac:

                dic[palabrac] = dic[palabrae]
                del dic[palabrae]
                dic[palabrac] = dic[palabrac]

            dic = dic[palabrac]
```

Ignora esta funcion (`aprender`) solo sirve para crear los diccionarios anidados

```py
def aprender(oraciones):
    recordal_palsu = conceptos_de_mi
    recordar_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra not in recordar_pal:
            recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
        if palabra not in recordal_palsu:
            recordal_palsu[palabra] = {}
        recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
        recordal_palsu = recordal_palsu[palabra]
```

Creamos unos diccionarios anidados, una cadena de la ruta a cambiar(`entrada1`) y la palabra corregida(`corregido1`), enviamos esos datos a la función.

```
conceptos_de_mi = {}
sobre_mi = {}  # ignoren esto
aprender(
    "Yo soy Lola una persona."
)  # Se crea un diccionario con lo siguiente
entrada1 = "Yo soy Lola una persona."  # palabrae/ para identificar la raiz y mantener orden
corregido1 = "Ella es Alice una maquina."  # palabrac/ se reemplaza las palabras diferentes
corregir(entrada1, corregido1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No acabo de entender claramente el resultado esperado tras la ejecución de `corregir()`, pero veo un par de cosas mal:

- Tienes dos bucles *anidados*, uno para recorrer las palabras de `oracione` y otro para las palabras de `oracionc`. Yo entiendo que en realidad **no quieres anidarlos**, sino que ambas oraciones se vayan recorriendo "en paralelo", de modo que habría un solo bucle en vez de dos, pero en cada iteración de ese único bucle irías avanzando a la vez por ambas oraciones. En la primera iteración obtendrías `palabrae="Yo"` y `palabrac="Ella"` y así sucesivamente.

  Para estas cosas (recorrer dos listas a la vez en un solo bucle) existe la función `zip(lista1, lista2)` que te va devolviendo parejas de datos tomados de cada una de las listas. Por cierto que se supone que ambas listas tienen la misma longitud. Si una es más corta, el bucle terminará cuando la más corta se agote. Esto puede plantear problemas en tu algoritmo, pero no lo tengo del todo claro.
- Tienes una instrucción que no hace nada: `dic[palabrac] = dic[palabrac]` Obviamente estás copiando una variable a sí misma, por lo que no cambia.

  No sé lo que pretendías aquí. A lo mejor es que esa instrucción directamente sobra, o tal vez querías hacer `dic[palabrae] = dic[palabrac]`. Evidentemente el resultado es muy diferente en cada uno de los casos, pero no acabo de entender lo que se pretende.

Este sería el código propuesto, que muestra cómo usar `zip()`:

```
def corregir(oracione, oracionc):
    """
    Esta funcion reemplaza palabras, busca todas las palabras de un diccionario
    en especifico usando una cadena de texto que especifica la ruta compara si
    es igual y remplaza el viejo nombre por la diferencia
    """

    dic = conceptos_de_mi

    for palabrae, palabrac in zip(oracione.split(), oracionc.split()):
        if palabrae in dic and palabrae != palabrac:
            dic[palabrac] = dic[palabrae]
            del dic[palabrae]
            #  dic[palabrae] = dic[palabrac]   # <--- Poner esto?
        dic = dic[palabrac]
```

Al ejecutar esta función tal como está (con la instrucción comentada y que por tanto no se ejecuta), mediante las líneas siguientes:

```
conceptos_de_mi = {}
sobre_ti = {}
aprender("Yo soy Lola una persona.")
entrada1 = "Yo soy Lola una persona." 
corregido1 = "Ella es Alice una maquina." 

print("Antes:", conceptos_de_mi)
corregir(entrada1, corregido1)
print("Después:", conceptos_de_mi)
```

Obtienes el resultado:

```
Antes: {'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {'una': {'persona.': {}}}}}}
Después: {'Ella': {'es': {'Alice': {'una': {'maquina.': {}}}}}}
```

Tiene pinta de ser lo que querías, pero claro, con este ejemplo tan sencillo no puede saberse.

Si, por otro lado, descomentamos la línea con la asignación dudosa, el resultado es muy diferente:

```
Antes: {'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {'una': {'persona.': {}}}}}}
Despues:
{'Ella': {'es': {'Alice': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}},
                 'Lola': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}}},
          'soy': {'Alice': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}},
                  'Lola': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}}}},
 'Yo': {'es': {'Alice': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}},
               'Lola': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}}},
        'soy': {'Alice': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}},
                'Lola': {'una': {'maquina.': {}, 'persona.': {}}}}}}
```

Lo que tiene toda la pinta de estar mal.

### Notas adicionales

No es buena idea tener variables globales como `sobre_mi`, `sobre_ti`, `conceptos_de_mi`, que son manipuladas desde esas funciones. Lo mejor para no liarse es que le pases como parámetro a cada función el diccionario que debe manipular. Por ejemplo:

```
def aprender(oraciones, recordar_pal, recordal_palsu):
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra not in recordar_pal:
            recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
        if palabra not in recordal_palsu:
            recordal_palsu[palabra] = {}
        recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
        recordal_palsu = recordal_palsu[palabra]
```

e invocarla por ejemplo así:

```
conceptos_de_mi = {}
sobre_ti = {}
aprender("Yo soy Lola una persona.", sobre_ti, conceptos_de_mi)
```

Análogamente para la función `corregir` debería recibir como parámetro el diccionario sobre el que debe operar.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que estaba intentando hacer, y por supuesto las palabras de las dos entradas siempre tendrán la misma cantidad de palabras, para que funcione de forma paralela aunque es posible talvez que en futuro pueda a ver una excepción, pero por ahora esta bien, no obstante cazando posibles bug hice un experimento donde en el diccionario que cambiara ya existia una anidación de diccionarios (Ella }es }muy }grande }hermana ) dicha anidación desaparece por completo y estoy intentando solucionarlo.

Comment: Creo que la solución sería copiar ese diccionario {Ella} y eliminarlo y luego cuando el nuevo diccionario este listo almacenar todas las ramas del {Ella} antiguo en el {Ella} nuevo. ¿como lo ves? podria usar la funcion (aprender) para enviar todas las ramas del viejo {Ella} al nuevo {Ella} pero deberia ser rama por rama.

Comment: Siii, olvidalo lo he logrado, logre hacerlo, pero aun no me lo puedo creer jaja, quiero publicar un tema para que veas como lo hice, y que me digas sobre posibles fallas, tal vez existe una forma mas simple de hacerlo jaja estoy muy feliz.

Comment: He a añadido la forma que corrige el bug, me gustaría que me dijeras si esta bien.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un problema a la hora de cambiar un diccionario raíz por otro y es que si existe una clave raíz igual a la primera clave de la palabra corregida, la vieja clave raíz se eliminará con todo su contenido por lo que es necesario guardar todo de la vieja raíz para luego volverlo almacenar en el nuevo diccionario creado.

```
def corregir(oracione, oracionc):
    """
    Esta funcion reemplaza palabras, busca todas las palabras de un diccionario
    en especifico usando una cadena de texto que especifica la ruta compara si
    es igual y remplaza el viejo nombre por la diferencia
    """
    activar=0
    cerrar1=0
    cerrar2=0
    activado=oracione.split()
    dic = conceptos_de_mi
    for palabrae, palabrac in zip(oracione.split(), oracionc.split()):
        activar += 1
        print("Suma de activar", activar)
        if activar <=1:
            pal_1=palabrac
        if palabrac in dic and cerrar1 <=0:
            pal=dic.pop(palabrac)
            cerrar1+=1
        if palabrae in dic and palabrae != palabrac:
            dic[palabrac] = dic[palabrae]
            del dic[palabrae]
        if palabrac in dic and cerrar2 <=0 and activar == len(activado):
            imprimex(pal,pal_1)
            print("Pal",pal)
            cerrar2 +=1
```

Es nueva función corregir funciona de esta manera, se hace un For para las oraciones para comparar, el primer if toma la primera palabra que se usara para enviar el prefijo a una funcion llamada imprimex, esta funcion toma todas las ramas de un diccionario y las imprime, pero en este caso no la vamos a imprimir sino que una vez copiamos el diccionario  antes que se elimine por el bug lo enviaremos para obtener sus ramas, una vez se concluye de cambiar todas las palabras y existe el nuevo diccionario, entonces la funcion imprimex se activa al completar el For, se envia a imprimex el diccionario viejo copiado y el prefijo, la primera palabra de ese viejo diccionario.

```
def imprimex(arbol,prefijo=""):
  if arbol== {}:
    print("De imprimex: ",prefijo)
    aprenderg(prefijo)
  else:
    for clave in arbol:
      imprimex(arbol[clave],prefijo+" "+clave)

  return
```

La funcion imprimex forma las ramas del viejo diccionario en cadenas y cada cadena luego se envia a otra funcion que se llama aprenderg.

```
def aprenderg(oraciones):
    recordal_palsu=conceptos_de_mi
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra not in recordal_palsu:
            recordal_palsu[palabra]={}
        #if palabra in recordal_palsu:
        #    recordal_palsu[palabra]={}
        recordal_palsu=recordal_palsu[palabra]
    return
```

La función aprenderg almacena la cadena en su respectivo orden dentro del nuevo diccionario(El viejo diccionario se almacena en el nuevo), ahora hagamos el experimento.

```
def aprender(oraciones):
    recordal_palsu=conceptos_de_mi
    recordar_pal = sobre_ti
    for palabra in oraciones.split():
        if palabra not in recordar_pal:
            recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
        if palabra not in recordal_palsu:
            recordal_palsu[palabra]={}
        recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
        recordal_palsu=recordal_palsu[palabra]
    return

conceptos_de_mi={}
sobre_mi={}
```

Creamos un diccionario anidado de (Yo)

```
aprender("Yo soy Lola una persona.")
aprender("Yo soy Pedro el picapiedra.")
aprender("Yo sere una buena programadora ya veras.")
```

Creamos un diccionario anidado preexistente de (Ella) que es el que se eliminaba por el bug y que ahora solo sera añadido al nuevo.

```
aprender("Ella es muy grande verdad.")
aprender("Ella es muy vieja jeje.")
aprender("Ella me mira.")


entrada1="Yo soy Lola una persona." #palabrae/ para identificar la raiz y mantener orden
corregido1="Ella es Alice una maquina." #palabrac/ se reemplaza las palabras no iguales/ ojo posibleme necesite eliminar todo el Yo}soy}Lola} etc porque las palabras pierden su sentido si se quedan.
corregir(entrada1,corregido1) #se llama la funcion
```

Comment: @abulafia Aqui.

Comment: ¿esto es respuesta o actualización de la pregunta?